# How to get the song title by inputting the position in the playlist array in user class?

Tags: java

I am having trouble of what to put to make the playlist array to work in the loop in the user. I am able to retrieve songList array in the Playlist Class, but the loop inside the User class won't accept the songList in the Playlist Class. Any Help!?

What it is asking for: a method that return the title of the song that is located at location pos in the playlist. The output is an empty string is the position is not a valid position.

Playlist Class:

```
public class Playlist {
//Instance Variables
private int numOfSongs;
private Songs[] songList;

// Constructors
public Playlist(int maxNumofSongs){
    this.numOfSongs = 0;
    this.songList = new Songs[maxNumofSongs];
}
//Getters 
    public Songs[] getSongList(){
        return this.songList;
    }
//Methods
public void addSong(String title, String filePath, String artist){
    Songs p = new Songs(title, filePath, artist);
    addSong(p);
}
public void addSong(Songs p){
    songList[this.numOfSongs] = p;
    this.numOfSongs++;
}
public Songs getSong(int pos){
    if (pos <= this.songList.length)
        return this.songList[pos];
    else
        return null;
}
public int getSongByTitle(String title){
    int pos = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.numOfSongs; i++)
        if (this.songList[i].getTitle() == title)
            pos = i;

    return pos;
}
public String toString(){
    String playlistDesc = "";
    playlistDesc += "Number of Songs added in Playlist: "+ numOfSongs;
    return playlistDesc;
}
```

}

User Class:

```
public class User {
//Instance Variables
private String name;
private String email;
private Playlist favoriteSongs;

//Constructors
public User(String name, String email, Playlist favoriteSongs){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    Songs[] songs = this.favoriteSongs.getSongList();
}
public User(String name, String email){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
//Setters
public void setPlayList(Playlist list){
    this.favoriteSongs = list;
}
//Get song title by inputting the position in the playlist array
public String getSongTitle(int pos){
    if (pos == this.favoriteSongs.getSongList())
        return Playlist.length[pos];
}
//Add new song to the playlist
public int addSong(String title, String filePath, String artist){
    for(int i=0; i<this.Playlist.length; i++) {
        if ((this.songList[i].getTitle().getArtist() == addSong(i))) // or what ever you want to compare
            return 0;
          }
          // if you do not found any thing
        return -1;
        }
}
// Counts how many songs with the same artist
public int artistSongCount(String artist){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < Playlist.numOfSongs.length; i++)
        if (this.favoriteSongs[i].getArtist() == artist)
            count++;

    return count;
}
}
//Print out details of user
public String toString(){
    String userOutput = "";
    userOutput += "Name: "+ name;
    userOutput += "Email: "+ email;
    return userOutput;
}
```

}

Comment: To get you started, you're referencing the class 'Playlist' in your user class, not the variable (favoriteSongs). Also take a look at the variable numOfSongs in Playlist, its a private variable and you're trying to call it in User.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, I'm assuming that this is a "learning exercise" of some kind, and I'm therefore going to give you hints rather than feeding you the correct code

I assume this is the method that is giving you difficulty.

```
//Get song title by inputting the position in the playlist array
public String getSongTitle(int pos){
    if (pos == this.favoriteSongs.getSongList())
        return Playlist.length[pos];
}
```

Hints:

1. That wouldn't compile.  What will be returned if the `if` rest fails?
2. About `pos == this.favoriteSongs.getSongList()`.  What is the type of the object returned by `getSongList()`?  Can you use `==` to compare an object that with an integer?  (Hint: No.)
3. About this `Playlist.length[pos]`.  What does that actually mean?  `Playlist` is a class so `Playlist.length` would be the name of a static field.  Does such a field exist in the `Playlist` class?
4. This is the Big Hint.  You have already got a method that returns the song at a given position in the playlist.  (Look for it!).  And I can see (code in `getSongByTitle`) how you get the title of a song.  So all you need to do is to do both of these things, and deal with the exceptional (non valid position) case.